# Scanning through file for given numbers - Java

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, io

I'm having a problem with a method. The task is to scan through a file containing different numbers. I want to make a method that will scan through the file for numbers 1 through 10.

Problem is that the while loop never activates. Whether this is because the value is never true or the method hasNextInt has a problem being used in this way I don't know.

I've checked using print statements inside and outside the loops in order to figure out the problem with the method.

Code:

```
package jr222er_lab4;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Histogram {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        File file = new File ("C:\\Users\\Johan\\Desktop\\histo.txt"); // imports our file
        Scanner n = new Scanner(file); // creates scanner

        System.out.println("Reading values from: "+file);
        int oneToHund = 0;
        int other = 0;

        while (n.hasNextInt()){
            int i = n.nextInt();
            if (i >= 1 && i <= 100){
                oneToHund++;
            }
            else 
                other++;
        }

        System.out.println("Numbers between [1,100]: "+oneToHund);
        System.out.println("Numbers out of this range: "+other);

        System.out.println("1 - 10 | "+firstTen(n));


    }



   // method in question 

    private static int firstTen(Scanner n){
        int result = 0;
        while (n.hasNextInt()){
            int i = n.nextInt();
            if (i >= 1 && i <= 10){
                result++;
            }
        }return result;
    }
```

Bonus question: I tried doing this in the main method but it seemed that the scanner **had searched through** the file with the first task (checking numbers 1 - 100), is this how it works?

Comment: forgot to look!!! 

figured out that the value in the while loop is false!

Comment: are you not storing integer within the file?

Comment: So, then you no longer need our help?

Comment: Still curious as to why the value is false

Comment: It all depends on what is on that file histo.txt, and how.

Answer (score 0):

`firstTen(n)` return 0 because Scanner object that pass to method already triversed cursor is at the last position. add `n = new Scanner(file);` before calling firstTen method